# Decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given two increasing function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with all $x \ge 0$. Moreover, $f(x) > g(x)
$ for all $x \ge 0$ and $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \left( {f(x) - g(x)} \right) = 0.$$
Is $d(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ a decreasing function ?

Comment: What are your own thoughts? How far did you get yourself?

Comment: needless to say, everything is supposed continuous, right? right?

Comment: YulOtani: Yes, those functions are continous.

Comment: rbm: With such condtions, I don't think $d(x)$ is decreasing for all nonegative $x$. However, if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are concave or convex, $d(x)$ maybe decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not even eventually decreasing. Consider 
$$
  f(x) 
= e^x \ \
  \mbox{ and } \ \
  g(x)
= \begin{cases}
  x                    & \mbox{ if } x \leq 1 \\
  e^x - \frac{1}{x}    & \mbox{ if } x \in (2n+1,2n+2], n \in \mathbb{N} \\
  e^x - \frac{1}{2n+2} & \mbox{ if } x \in [2n, 2n+1], n \in \mathbb{N}; \\
  \end{cases}
$$
they satisfy your conditions but on intervals of the form $[2n,2n+1]$ $f(x) - g(x)$ is constant and therefore not decreasing. There are infinitely many such intervals.

Comment: Are you sure that it has to be eventually decreasing?

Comment: Yes. It is always positive but has $0$ as its limit.

Comment: There are lots of functions that are always positive and have zero as their limit but are not eventually decreasing.

Comment: Andreas Blass is right. I thought that the monotonicity of $f$ and $g$ would ensure it for the function going to zero, but it doesn't. I will try to make an example

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=e^x$, and let $f(x)= e^x+\frac{1}{6}(\sin^2 x+0.01) e^{-x}$.

Note that the derivative of $\frac{1}{6}(\sin^2 x+0.01) e^{-x}$ takes on positive values for arbitrarily large $x$, and negative value for arbitrarily large $x$.

And $f(x)$ is increasing when $x\ge 0$. This is because the absolute value of the derivative of $\frac{1}{6}(\sin^2 x+0.01) e^{-x}$ is "small" in comparison with the derivative of $e^x$.

The above is very close to the idea of coffeemath, with small differences of detail.